# What does net/context's cancel() function do?

Tags: go

[net/context](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context)'s `WithDeadline()` and `WithTimeout()` functions both return a `cancel` function, which docs say to always call with a defer, such as:

```
func slowOperationWithTimeout(ctx context.Context) (Result, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 100*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel()  // releases resources if slowOperation completes before timeout elapses
```

But what "resources" are actually being released in this function?

Comment: Does it matter? Shouldn't it just be considered an implementation detail. (It closes the `Done()` channel and removes the new child context from the list of children the parent context knows of, this allows the child context to be garbage collected.)

Comment: @DaveC: It's not that it matters... it's that I'm curious. And in so far as understanding what the code you write *does* matters, it matters :)

Answer (score 0):

The code example you give comes from [the `context.WithTimeout` documentation](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context/#WithTimeout), here it is again slightly modified:

```
func slowOperationWithTimeout(parentContxt context.Context) (Result, error) {
    childContext, cancel := context.WithTimeout(parentContxt, 100*time.Millisecond)
    defer cancel()  // releases resources if slowOperation completes before timeout elapses
    return slowOperation(childContext)
}
```

(Here I've renamed `ctx` to make it clear which I'm talking about, in real code it's better to just use `ctx` as you don't want or need to distinguish the parent/child contextes.)

Calling the returned cancel function does (at least) two important things.
First, it closes the channel that `childContext.Done()` returns. This might be import if, for example, `slowOperation` started something in a goroutine with that context (or a [grand]child context).

Second, cancelling `childContext` tells `parentContext` to forget about it.
There are references to the child context in the local variable and another in the parent's list of all it's children (and any references `slowOperation` may have kept). If it's not cancelled when it's no longer needed, the parent wastes space keeping it around until the child context eventually times out and cancels itself, among other things that can delay the child context and it's done channel from being garbage collected.

It's also possible a context implementation (or a future change) could have other resources used until cancelled.
If the documentation says you should do something, then do it (even if it were to do nothing in current implementations).
In that sense, the answer to "Why?" for such things is simply, "Because the documentation said that's the correct way to use it".